# Node-RED(Bluemix)の「http request」ブロックを使ったPostリクエスト方法

Tags: node.js, bluemix

最近Node-REDを触り始めました。
かなり楽しいのですが、合点がいくまでもう少し・・・という状態です。

さて、表題のとおり、パラメタをPOSTするのがうまくいきません。
（パラメタを連結してGETするのはできました）

色々調べてみると
msg.payload に詰めるのだろうと思いますが・・・
header の指定なども上手くいっていないようです

何かヒントなどいただければ助かります

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下にそれらしい参照URLがありました。
msg.headersに格納するみたいです。
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/276380/how-do-i-send-form-data-in-http-request-node-with.html

```
msg.payload = { a: "one", b: "two" };
msg.headers = {'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};
return msg;
```